# One-way speed of light and refractive index

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, optical-materials

It is recognized that special relativity does not require the speed of light to be isotropic, and having light propagate in each direction with the same speed is just a convenient postulate (see e.g. [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_speed_of_light) and references therein, or a recent [popular science video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTn6Ewhb27k)).

I was wondering how would the use of an alternative, anisotropic convention change our description of refractive index. Let's say that we have detector/emitter A which generates two parallel pulses, one travelling through vacuum, the other through a cylinder with a refractive index larger than one. The two pulses arrive on detector/emitter B in a fixed distance. Based on the difference between times of arrival and our knowledge of the material properties, we can measure the speed of light. By sending pulses from B to A, we could measure the speed of light in the other direction.

It is obvious that to preserve the impossibility to measure the one way speed of light, the refractive index of the cylinder must become anisotropic. However, in one special case of the anisotropic convention, the speed of light in one direction can be infinite. Then the refractive index in this direction must also be divergent (infinite) to preserve the equivalence in measured delays in each direction. Are my conclusions correct? And how should I interpret the infinite refractive index?

$$
\Delta t_1 = \frac{n_1 l}{c_1} - \frac{l}{c_1}\\
\Delta t_2 = \frac{n_2 l}{c_2} - \frac{l}{c_2}\\
\Rightarrow\\
n_2 = 1 + \frac{c_2}{c_1}(n_1-1)
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of "index of refraction" is made within the isotropic coordinate system, and should be understood to be implicitly referencing it. Its natural extension to an anisotropic coordinate system is that it refers to the ratio between the velocities in the isotropic coordinate system. If we insist on retaining the definition of it being the ratio of the velocities in our coordinate system, then we end up with two different indices. Since the values of those indices would depend on the coordinate system, rather than anything physical, they would have no physical meaning.

Comment: I see, the divergent behavior is a direct result of the strange choice of coordinate transform related to defining c2 = infinity. I should have thought of that. Thank you!